# How to implement overlay for android appwidget?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

guys.

I'm making widget for some app, which places on home screen of phone. In Configure Activity I want to add overlay option - checkbox. But I'm not sure if I appwidgets could use overlay.

Could you tell me, please, can appwidget use overlay (be shown not only on homescreen, but on the top of another apps) and if so - how can I implement overlay for android app widget?

P.S.: I'm wannabe android junior dev, and would be glad to take source code as an example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dialog fragment for that so that it covers whole screen

```
public class OverlayFragment extends DialogFragment {

    static Overlay newInstance() {

        Overlay f = new Overlay();
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme);
        this.setCancelable(false);


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        final Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
        window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
        window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.circular_progress_bar, container, false);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#80000000"));
        getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        return view;
    }
```

R.layout.circular_progress_bar is layout that will contain progressbar

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Nice way, but if I want to change  appwidget code, is there any way to make overlay for widget?

Comment: What do u mean by that

Comment: I told 'bout appwidgets, that placed in homescreen. And I want to use overlay for them so they will be on top (or above) other applications. I hope my explanation is clear)).